# Rails 6: ActionText breaks my links, how to disable URL encoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

I use action_text with a model and need to type in links using liquid template variables, for example:

```
Contact us at: <a href="mailto:support@{{website.domain_name}}">support@{{website.domain_name}}</a>
```

However action_text breaks these links by encoding the curly brackets :( it also does it in src img tags src attributes :(

```
Contact us at <a href="mailto:support@%7B%7Bwebsite.domain_name%7D%7D">support@example.com</a>
```

It does the same if I use my own tags eg [domain_name] anywhere in href or src attributes.

I just want my HTML to be left alone, untouched, exactly as I enter it, I don't need any "help" encoding URLs tfank you very much action_text/Rails.

Is there a way to fix or disable this unwanted behavior?

Later edit:

Turns out this trix thing is also removing any other HTML such as tables, divs and so on :( it even removes HTML data- attributes :(( how do I disable this? I just want a friendly HTML editor with basic functions (bold, underline, paragraphs, headings...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGI`. Example, If you have a `Post` model with `has_rich_text :content`, then In your `show` views, you can do this:

```
<%= (CGI.unescapeHTML @post.content.to_s).html_safe %>
```

Trix uses ActionText, it's own Rich text, so you first convert it to string with `to_s`, then encode the HTML stuff with `CGI`, then finally make the whole string `html_safe` to show in browser.

More context: No matter what you type in `ActionText` or `text_area`, back in the database everything will be stored as string. Databases don't save HTML. So you'll want to save HTML as a string only, then after receiving it in views, you can perform encoding and stuff to convert that back to HTML.

---

You can even use [HTML Entities](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities) or Nokogiri(a bit complex)

Answer (score 0):

## I use `CGI::unescape`

In my model I have something like:

```rb
class Post
   has_rich_text :content

   def decoded_content
      CGI::unescape(content.to_s)
   end
end
```

Then use it on posts objects. i.e. `Post.first.decoded_content`

---

`CGI::unescapeHTML` or `CGI::unescape_html` did not work for me.